# Where does the CRC part come from?

Tags: crc

Consider the following exam question:

> Use the CRC polynomial generator x2 + 1 to find out if the following
>   received message contains any errors : 10111111. Show the exact user
>   data received separate from the actual CRC.

The Provided Answer:

> Generator Binary: 101
>
> Two Zeros are appended to the message.
>
> 101 / 10111111 => Remainder = 01
>
> Original Message= 101111 CRC = 11

I am trying to figure out how the CRC part of 11 is derived.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it's saying is simply that the message `10111111` consists of the content `101111` and the CRC `11`.  The CRC of the content is appended to the content to make up the message.  If the message is received correctly, then dividing the entire message by the CRC polynomial should result in a remainder of zero.  I.e. the CRC of the content plus a correct CRC is necessarily zero.

Since the remainder was 01, the message must be in error.